# Issue with 'rm' Command: No such file or directory error for '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list'

Tags: linux, apache, deployment

I encountered an error while trying to remove a file using the `rm` command on my Ubuntu system. The error message is as follows:

```
rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list': No such file or directory
```

I've tried running the command multiple times, but the issue persists. It's worth noting that I'm facing a similar problem with the `sudo apt-get update` command, which is also not working as expected. I've come across a related issue titled "**Sudo apt-get update is not working in ubuntu**."

Could someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue with the 'rm' command error and the 'sudo apt-get update' problem? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.